# Conditional groupBy in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can one apply conditional grouping in an Angular `ng-repeat` directive?

For example, in the below code, I want to `groupBy:'var1'`, but only when some variable, or expression, `dontGroup` evaluates to true. I don't want to have the bottom `tr` row duplicated specifically for the `dontGroup` variable in my HTML because the information cannot be loaded in via a template for a second `tr` due to the main table being controlled by a directive and needing the template in the DOM before initialization. If there's a way to do this that I'm overlooking, please let me know. I'm utilizing `ng-table`.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, data) in $data | groupBy:'var1'">
        <td ng-bind="key">
            <!-- Grouped header info here. -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in data"> <!-- Repeat $data when `dontGroup` evaluates to true, 
                                                     otherwise repeat pre-grouped data from the `groupBy` filter above -->
        <td ng-bind="item.var2">
            <!-- Individual item info here. -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, I want the lower `ng-repeat` function to repeat `$data` as `data` only when `dontGroup` evaluates to true, but otherwise I want `$data` to be run through the `groupBy` filter such that the data can have a header for the group.

I also cannot just drop an `ng-if` on the header row when `dontGroup` evaluates to true because I need the data to sort by other variables such as `var2`, `var3`, etc, and not have the `var1` grouping affect that.

**A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/336g5e9e/2/) for you to play with showing both wanted functionalities.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm setting a conditional on the header row and returning a dummy object when `dontGroup` evaluates to true. It does mean, however, that `var1` can't be equal to "test" in the grouped array, else the header won't be shown. "test" will just be a protected value.

Further, you could use this syntax with other filters when off of the grouping, as shown below.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, data) in (dontGroup ? {'test': $data} : ($data | groupBy:'var1'))" ng-if="key != 'test'">
        <td ng-bind="key">

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: 'var2')">
        <td ng-bind="item.var2">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/336g5e9e/3/)

> Check John Babb's answer for offloading some of this logic into the controller!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the groupBy to reference a function and in the controller you can do a custom groupBy that will check for an indicator of how to group.  Please see the following docs for more information.

http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-api

Here is a rough attempt which should show the concept.

http://jsfiddle.net/wwgo4eo4/

```
//template
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="clickGroupBY()"/>
  <table>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, data) in $data | groupBy:valueGroupBY">

//controller
$scope.willgroupby = true;
$scope.valueGroupBY = function(group) {
if($scope.willgroupby) {
    return group.var1
}

return group.var2
}
$scope.clickGroupBY = function clickGroupBY() {
    $scope.willgroupby = !$scope.willgroupby;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I ran with the solution you came back with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121655/460782) and cleaned it up. see the following: http://jsfiddle.net/r1mss7s0/1/

I also found this to be informative about the filters you are using:
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/wiki/Common-Questions

Comment: But, I don't want to group at all when `dontGroup` evaluates to true. I may want to sort by any number of variables. In the case of any variable except `var`, I don't want a header. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, this is cleaner in the template, and offloads it to the controller. You'd likely want to put an `ng-if=' key != "" '` in there to make sure the first header doesn't key shown, but then the protected value is empty, whereas you might want an empty `var1` value, so users looking at this solution should change that to their own protected value. I'll upvote you on this, but because you're utilizing the controller my answer is likely more attractive to most people because they don't have to manage two code sets for one thing.